# SBT disconnect database clients on finished tests

Tags: scala, sbt

I am trying to execute code which is in main project from sbt task:

```
lazy val disconnectClients = taskKey[Unit]("Disconnect postgres clients after tests.")

disconnectClients := {
  (testLoader in Test).value
    .loadClass("com.companyname.DBDisconnector")
    .getMethod("close")
    .invoke(null).asInstanceOf[Unit]
}
```

Where DBDisconnector:

```
class DBDisconnector {
  ...
  def close(): Unit = {
    println("-------> DISCONNECT <--------")
    ds.close()
  }
}
```

but nothing happens..
what am I doing wrong ? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Pass an instantiated object to `invoke` instead of `null` like so

```
lazy val disconnectClients = taskKey[Unit]("Disconnect postgres clients after tests.")
disconnectClients := {
  val loader = (testLoader in Test).value
  val cls = loader.loadClass("example.DBDisconnector")
  val disconnector = cls.newInstance()
  cls.getMethod("close").invoke(disconnector)
}
```

[`Tests.Cleanup`](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Testing.html#Setup+and+Cleanup) is another way of achieving similar cleanup:

```
testOptions in Test += Tests.Cleanup { loader =>
  val cls = loader.loadClass("example.DBDisconnector")
  val disconnector = cls.newInstance()
  cls.getMethod("close").invoke(disconnector)
}
```